# How to select SuperTab completion suggestion without creating new line?

Tags: vim, code-completion, supertab

When I hit Enter on SuperTab's popup suggestion, it automatically creates a new line at the end of the inserted keyword.

Is it possible to select an option in the SuperTab popup without creating a new line?

More specifically, is there a way for me to configure `space` as the method of selecting the code completion suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
inoremap <expr> <Space> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : " "
```

Note the `<C-y>` that accepts currently selected option, you may want to use it directly instead of remapping space. You will see more in `:h popupmenu-keys`.

Answer (score 6):

Put this in your .vimrc

```
let g:SuperTabCrMapping=1
```