# How to accept a suggestion from Vim YouCompleteMe plugin

Tags: vim, autocomplete

When there are multiple complete suggestions from Vim plugin YouCompleteMe, how do I accept the one I want ?

What I currently do is pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, I just want to know if I got it right.

Comment: See also [How to select SuperTab completion suggestion without creating new line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7870086).

Comment: Super weird that we have to ask this. You'd think this be the first thing listed in the docs, but it's not at all.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To accept the current insert completion entry use `<c-y>`. Think of it as "yes".

For more help see:

```
:h complete_ctrl-y
```

Answer (score 13):

Usually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> (*yes*); read up `:help popupmenu-keys`.

Answer (score 11):

`Ctrl-Y` is default, but you can add other key bindings by adding this line to your `.vimrc`:

`let g:ycm_key_list_stop_completion = ['<C-y>', '<CR>']`

In this ^ example, you can use either `Ctrl-Y` or `Enter` to accept the completion and free up the cursor.

Answer (score -6):

For some reason, I think that you didn't really read the documentation and/or the README:

> When the user sees a useful completion string being offered, they press the TAB key to accept it. This inserts the completion string. Repeated presses of the TAB key cycle through the offered completions.

Comment: I read that, and it says "repeated presses of the TAB key cycle through the offered completions" It did not say how to pick one if there are more than one.

Comment: If you want the third suggestion you hit tab 2 times: the word you wanted is inserted so you are supposed to simply continue your typing.

Comment: @romainl But what if I just finished typing as the word is completed? What I do is hit the Esc key and the suggestion is gone. Instead of the completed word I have there only the letters that I typed. What is the proper way of accepting the suggestion and leaving the instert mode instead of just pressing Esc? Or is it possible to accept the word with Esc too?

Comment: Actually, using `TAB` and `SHIFT+TAB` is a good solution for traversing between suggestions and releasing and continuing to code. awesome, thanks. I leave an upvote.